# Calculations are not coming in, what am I doing wrong

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and cannot seem to get the calculations for the code below to come in outside of the one calculation when I input 1 for distance which then calculates to $1.80.  I have an if else that should recognize that as not meeting the minimum and therefore calculate it as $5.00, but it just calculates $1.80.    Can you please point me in the right direction as to what I am missing for the needed calculations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MINFARE '$5.00'


int main() {
    //Declare all of the variables types and their data types and values as applicable.
    float distance, totalFare;
    int numberOfPassengers, airport;


    //Prompt passenger to enter the total distance (measured to 1/10 of a mile) with a keyboard
    printf("Please enter the total distance, ");
    printf("enter it measured to 1/10 mile, e.g. 25.5:  ");
    scanf("%f", &distance);

    //Prompt the user to enter the number of passengers
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of passengers: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfPassengers);

    printf("\nAre you going or coming from the Airport?  ");
    printf("Enter (1) for <yes> and (2) for <no>:  ");
    scanf("%d", &airport);

    if(airport == 1) {
        totalFare = (1.80 * distance) + 2.00;
    }
    else {
        totalFare = 1.80 * distance;
    }

    /*Calculate the fare amount with the number of passengers, such that, the initial rider is charge the fare only,
    the first additional passenger charge is the fare plus $1.00 and additional passengers are charge an additional
    $0.50 per passenger*/

    if (numberOfPassengers <= 1) {
        totalFare = 1.80 * distance;
    }
    else {
        totalFare = (1.80 * distance) + 1.00 + (0.50 * (numberOfPassengers - 1));
    }

    printf("\nYou entered %g as the total miles, %d passengers, and %d for Airport cab ride.", distance, numberOfPassengers, airport);

    if (totalFare>5.00) {
        printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t MINFARE.");
    }
    else {
    //Print the statements below based on the user input and the calculations total Fare for cab ride
       printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t $%.2f",totalFare);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'$5.00'` is multi-character character literal, whose value is implementation-defined and won't be what you think. (but fortunately you don't use this value in your code)

Comment: So would I be better to declare it as a variable and assign the value of $5.00 dollars to it?

Comment: After helping with your last question it's good to see you've got to grips with the variables in the `if`s like `totalFare = (1.80 * distance) + 1.00 + (0.50 * (numberOfPassengers - 1));`, good job.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I appreciate the positive feedback.  As I said, i will get there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @MikeCAT, but just want to clarify this part about symbolic constant (`#define MINFARE '$5.00'`). In C single quotes (`' '`) represents a single character, not a string (You are probably confusing it with some other languages like python that works diferently). As already pointed what you write is a multi-character character literal and not string what you actually wanted. If you want to define a string in C you must use double quotes (`" "`) (Because even a single character string actually have two characters, that one and `'\0'` which is an indicator that marks the end of a string).

Answer (score 0):

You are limitting the maximum instead of minimum and goint to print a string "MINFARE" when the maximum is hit.

One fix is:

- `totalFare>5.00` should be `totalFare<5.00` to have the value work as minimum, not maximum.
- `#define MINFARE '$5.00'` should be `#define MINFARE "$5.00"`.
- `printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t MINFARE.");` should be `printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t " MINFARE ".");`

Better fix avoiding using magic number is:

- `#define MINFARE '$5.00'` should be `#define MINFARE 5.00`
- `totalFare>5.00` should be `totalFare<MINFARE`
- `printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t MINFARE.");` should be `printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t $%.2f.", MINFARE);`

Comment: So this definitely helped, but I am not getting the expected results with when airport is added and when the minfare print function happens.  Instead of $5.00, I get The total fare owed is:  4.40815e-315.  I updated the code as per your direction above to: if (totalFare<5.00) {
        printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t %g", MINFARE);

Comment: @AnnetteKitz [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bpWJFfd3GUj71pxC). Didn't you forget to fix the definition of `MINFARE`?

Comment: Sorry, no, I updated it to: #define MINFARE '5.00'    and   if (totalFare<5.00) {
        printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t $%g", MINFARE);

Comment: `#define MINFARE '5.00'` is NOT in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, and after I corrected the one item, I am now getting the minimum.  My apologies.  Can you tell me why the airport charge is coming in properly by any chance.  I am thinking I need to add to my initial if else statement for the airport charge calculation.  Does this make sense or should I come at it from a different angle?

Comment: I think the `if(airport == 1) { ... } else { ... }` part can be removed because: 1. The calculated `totalFare` will be overwritten without its value being used in later calculation. 2. I see no specifications that says that whether "going or coming from the Airport" will affect the fare here.

Comment: So I want $2.00 added to the total fare if the user answers number 1 for the airport question.  I also want $1.00 added if additional passengers is 1 and then 0.50 for 2 or more additional passengers.  The base fare is just the distance times the 1.80 if the user answers 0 for additional passengers and no to airport.

Comment: If you want $2.00 added, you should add that: you should add `if(airport == 1) totalFare += 2.00;` before `printf("\nYou entered ...`

Comment: All, I figured out the final calculation, thank you for all of your assistance, I really appreciate it.